# PHP - dynamic display of CSV data with pagination

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and scripting languages. I am designing a web page where I need to display the contents of CSV file in a paginated format. Also, I am going to have a range selection which will enable the users to select a range value. After selecting the range value, I need to display only those values from CSV which satisfy the given criteria. This is the code I have so far.

```
<?php 
      $totalcolumns = $_SESSION["totalcolumns"];
?>

<!-- Activate Simple Slider on your input -->
  <h2>Keyword Scores</h2>
  <?php

$i = 1;
while (++$i <= $_SESSION['totalcolumns']) {
    $range = $_SESSION["min-column-$i"] . ',' . $_SESSION["max-column-$i"];?>
        <br><input type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="<?php echo $range ?>" data-slider-step="1">
        <?php } ?>

 <!--<input type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="1,500" data-slider-step="1"> 
 <script>
    $("[data-slider]")
        .each(function () {
            var range;
            var input = $(this);
            $("<span>").addClass("output")
                .insertAfter(input);
            range = input.data("slider-range").split(",");
            $("<span>").addClass("range")
                .html(range[0])
                .insertBefore(input);
            $("<span>").addClass("range")
                .html(range[1])
                .insertAfter(input);
        })
        .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
            $(this).nextAll(".output:first")
                .html(data.value.toFixed(2));
        });
</script>
```

As per the above code, I am able to display all the CSV values successfully. As per the above code, I also have the slider using which the user can select the range value that he wants to display. For example, let's assume we have below contents in the CSV file.

- **authorID   k1   k2    k3**
- author1       4    5    7
- author2       6    5    8
- author3       9    1    2

So, as per the above data, I will have 3 sliders (for k1,k2 and k3). The sliders will have the range as per the min and max of the values in columns *k1, k2 and k3*. So for k1, the slider will have the min value of 4 and max value of 9. I can select any value between 4 and 9 and only those values satisfying the given criteria need to be displayed in the screen. For example, for k1, if I select the value 5, the CSV file should be displayed as below.

- **authorID    k1  k2  k3**
- author2     6    5    8
- author3     9    1    2

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question?

Comment: Yeah, I am able to display the CSV file fully without any problem. I am not able to display, only the contents that the user wishes to see..